# Why is there no Stack Overflow YouTube channel and/or stackoverflow.tv

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, videos, youtube

Has a Stack Overflow YouTube channel or a stackoverflow.tv site ever been contemplated, in doing so taking advantage of a medium where the Stack Overflow experience could be expanded and extended beyond reading material and the (nonetheless proven) Q&A format?

**EDIT:** I'm not talking about [StackHQ](http://www.youtube.com/user/StackHQ) or that [Careers 2.0 channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/StackCareers) that has the one video, I'm talking full-fledged [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) style but a lot wider in terms of technologies.

Beyond the (undoubtedly enormous) challenges, there are also enormous potential rewards.

I'm convinced this has, at least at some point, been on the table and would be interested to hear what made it an unsuitable medium to further explore.

To clarify the question, I can easily imagine that:

- digging into the audio-visual market would be easy for a site that has already reached a certain standard, status and reputation
- there are a lot of very smart people on Stack Overflow who are not only celebrated authors but also experienced public speakers who, given the chance / asked / coerced could bring a wide range of topics in their respective fields of expertise to a wide audience
- this *might* be a cash cow in terms of ad revenue (I could be way off here, I have no idea how that "world" works...)
- there could be a standard in terms of audio-video quality and content that I sometimes miss on YouTube
- ...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/user/StackHQ?feature=watch

Comment: @Bart Is that official?

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya I guess the answer to that is quasi-semi-sorta-yes-but-maybe-sideways-in-a-way.

Comment: that seems to be a really long word for 'no'

Comment: Obligatory comment: [Votes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: There's the [podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/), which sorta falls into this category... ish.

Comment: And, as a small time video creator on YouTube, the money you get is abysmal. I think I got something around $4 for about 16000 views, and yes, SO does have a large amount of users, I doubt many would want to sit through a 5 minute video in the middle of the day.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Good point, but of course the same goes for other video channels. And also: congrats on the 4$ :-P

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII ,  I used to think the same thing, but it's astonishing how many young people these days actually enjoy learning *everything* via videos, *including* coding. You and I might never watch one in a million years, but there are plenty of people who apparently would.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270574/an-experiment-stack-overflow-tv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A long time ago, a team called CHAOS existed to try lots of wacky new ideas with the goal of promoting and expanding the Stack Exchange network.

As part of that project, the [StackHQ YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/StackHQ) was created. (Yes, that is an "official" SE property.) For a while, we ran a web series called "The Question in Conference Room B", whose purpose was to highlight interesting questions and answers from around the network (not just Stack Overflow) and entertain people at the same time.

We stopped doing that for two reasons:

1. The CHAOS project ended and the team disbanded - some members moved into different roles within SE, and some left to explore other opportunities
2. It turns out that producing a high-quality web series is an enormous amount of work and very difficult to do well without a large team. The company is growing quickly, but we are not yet at the point where we can afford to invest in our own television department.

So to answer your question, yes, it has been considered, but we're not pursuing it right now. As mentioned in the comments, though, we do have a [podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) - and who knows, maybe someday we'll have a television studio in our office.

Answer (score 1):

For about a year now, Stack Overflow the company  appears to have [its own official YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2hxYQtGLEkcOMK4h8JRycA/), with video uploads of average once about 2 months. (6 in a year.)

While not "Channel9 style", it's surely better than nothing as it used to be. :)