# Is the Stack Exchange YouTube channel still being updated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, youtube

On the Stack Exchange YouTube channel, all of the videos seem to have been uploaded one year ago. Has it been abandoned, or will there be another large video that takes one year to produce posted on it soon?

Comment: I don't believe Brett works for Stack Exchange anymore, so probably not.

Comment: @animuson Who's Brett?

Comment: The guy who posted about [the start of that web series](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127106/new-web-series-the-question-in-conference-room-b).

Comment: @animuson His profile still says he works for Stack Exchange, but he does not have the moderator diamond anymore...

Comment: I can't find any of the people involved with that on the Stack Exchange Team page anymore. Their profiles are likely just outdated because they haven't visited in a long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this post by Laura](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182341/why-is-there-no-stack-overflow-youtube-channel-and-or-stackoverflow-tv):

> As part of that project, the [StackHQ YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/StackHQ) was created. (Yes, that is an "official" SE property.) For a while, we ran a web series called "The Question in Conference Room B", whose purpose was to highlight interesting questions and answers from around the network (not just Stack Overflow) and entertain people at the same time.
>
> We stopped doing that for two reasons:
>
> 1. The CHAOS project ended and the team disbanded - some members moved into different roles within SE, and some left to explore other opportunities
> 2. It turns out that producing a high-quality web series is an enormous amount of work and very difficult to do well without a large team. The company is growing quickly, but we are not yet at the point where we can afford to invest in our own television department.

So, looks like it's a dead channel.