# Why has the Stack Exchange Tumblr account stopped posting stuff?

Tags: discussion

I signed up for a Tumblr account today, and was forced to follow 3 blogs. I searched for Stack Exchange, and found http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/. I of course followed that, StackStatus, and some other random blog which I promptly unfollowed so I could get past the registration process.

But then I noticed [the most recent post](http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/post/42667140816/why-are-there-so-few-english-words-that-begin-with) was on February 9th, 2013. Why has the Stack Exchange Tumblr account stopped posting things?

Comment: ... the real question is why did you sign up for a Tumblr?

Comment: ... the real question is why did *Stack Exchange* use Tumblr?

Comment: @hichris Because I am now obligated to join various annoying social networks for my website :-P I will always refuse to sign up for Facebook, though!

Comment: @Doorknob You do realize Instagram is owned by Facebook, right? ;)

Comment: @hichris How is that relevant to Tumblr?

Comment: @Doorknob *to join **various annoying social networks*** If you have to join Instagram... *shudder*

Comment: @hichris No. NEVAR! >:O

Comment: What is wrong with using facebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This blog is run by CHAOS.

[Long since dead.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182341/why-is-there-no-stack-overflow-youtube-channel-and-or-stackoverflow-tv)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204755/is-the-stack-exchange-youtube-channel-still-being-updated/204760#204760

Comment: Hrm, I guess I wasn't paying enough attention. Thanks!